# opening url based file in filestream

Tags: sharepoint-2010, filestream

I have a document which is stored in doc library of sharepoint..now i want to open and read data from it ...how can i do it ..filestream does not take url as input ..please help.

Answer (score 1):

Try [SPFile.OpenBinaryStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms470901.aspx)

From [SharePoint 2007 - Read content from SPFile](http://www.myrocode.com/post/2009/03/05/SharePoint-2007-Read-content-from-SPFile.aspx):

```
string content = string.Empty;
using (SPSite oSite = new SPSite("http://localhost/"))
{
    using (SPWeb oWeb = oSite.OpenWeb())
    {
        SPDocumentLibrary doclib = (SPDocumentLibrary)oWeb.GetList(DocLibUrl);
        SPFile htmlFile = doclib.Items[0].File;
        using (System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(htmlFile.OpenBinaryStream()))
        {
            content = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to use a HTTPRequest object to retrieve the file. Here is a code example:

http://geeknotes.wordpress.com/2008/01/10/saving-a-possibly-binary-file-from-a-url-in-c/